# Merging multiple arrays using php

Tags: php, arrays, excel, parsing, xlsx

I am currently trying to figure out how to merge a collection of arrays in php.

```
foreach ($Col as $Row)
{   
    echo("<pre>");
      print_r($Row); // This returns the arrays below
    echo("</pre>");
}
```

When I run the foreach statement it returns the following:

```
Array
(
  [0] => First Name
  [1] => Last Name
  [2] => Username
)

Array
(
  [0] => Bob
  [1] => Dill
  [2] => DBob
)


Array
(
  [0] => Amy
  [1] => Simpson
  [2] => Asimp
)

Array
(
  [0] => Doug
  [1] => James
  [2] => LJames
)
```

Is there anyway I can merge the following arrays into one array as I am interested in only grabbing the username from all of the arrays and merging them into a new array.

Comment: Why your problem is concerned with Excel ?

Comment: Its seems that your data are already grabbed into the single variable $Col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get the usernames, could just :

1. point it directly (which is index 2)
2. pop the first array (which looks like a header), search for `username` which can be used as your marker.

After determining where it its, you can use it in a simple loop. Consider this example:

**#1**

```
$values = array( array('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Username'), array('Bob', 'Dill', 'DBob'), array('Amy', 'Simpson', 'Asimp'), array('Doug', 'James', 'LJames'), );
$usernames = array();
array_shift($values);
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $usernames[] = $value[2];
}
```

**#2**

```
$values = array( array('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Username'), array('Bob', 'Dill', 'DBob'), array('Amy', 'Simpson', 'Asimp'), array('Doug', 'James', 'LJames'), );
$usernames = array();
$header = array_shift($values);
$username_key = array_search('Username', $header); // find out which column is username
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $usernames[] = $value[$username_key];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($usernames);
echo '</pre>';
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DBob
    [1] => Asimp
    [2] => LJames
)
```

Comment: Your code works great except you've hard coded the array inside of the values variable. How can I add my results inside of an array from the foreach loop?

Comment: @coletrain the `$values` are supposed to be hardcoded because that is just a sample data. given, if the sample data (which is in this example, is `$values`) are the same in structure as your `$Col` then it should work the same. you just need to substitute, like :`$values = $Col;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($Col as $Row)
{   
    foreach($Row as $k=>$val){
      $arr[count($arr)]=$val;
     }

}  

print_r($arr);
```